# in html, can language input be changed on an ITEM basis?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Have a user form containing numerous lines similar to this:

```
<h2>Parts of Body</h2>
<div>
  English: <input name='body_en-1' />
  &nbsp;
  Thai: <input name='body_th-1' />
  &nbsp;
  Description: <input name='body_descr-1' />
  <br/>
  ...
</div>
```

problem: killing the users switching the keyboards back and forth between the two languages - many mistakes, *lots* of complaining.

is there anyway that `INPUT.focus()` could switch the keyboard between languages for the user?

Comment: I also need this, but I delayed it to another time, because I have other priorities, :)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the lang attribute? Would using that help at all? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight answer... No, you can't. 
What you CAN do is this, you can emulate another keyboard layout by mapping different keyboard layouts to the English keyboard layout. 
for example, you can use this for the Nordic layout:

```
    <input name="Swedish" type="text" onkeypress="convertToNordic(event, this);" onkeyup="doBackSpace(this);" />
    <script>
function convertToNordic(evt, handle) {
    switch (String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode)){
        case '[' : handle.value += 'å';break;
        case ';' : handle.value += 'ö';break;
        case '\'' : handle.value += 'ä';break;
        default : handle.value += String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode);

    }
}
function doBackSpace(handle){
    handle.value = handle.value.substr(0,handle.value.length-1);

}
    </script>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LsMk/7/)

and you can work your way from there

Comment: in Sweedish, it being somewhat sane, maybe workable.  Thai has 40 vowels, 64 consonants, plus a dozen tone markers and special symbols.  A vowel, for example, may precede, follow, be on top or be underneath a consonant, or combination, or omitted.  far too insane to try.  anyway, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @ccyoung, the complexity of the language isn't in question here, I do the same for Arabic language (which is pretty damn complex) the main idea is you take the input from the English keyboard and substitute it with corresponding value in another layout. I don't see how the language complexity gets in the middle, check this [Thai Keyboard](http://www.thai-keyboard.com/)

Answer (score 0):

No, and you cannot even know whether some particular keyboard layout (like some specific layout for Thai) is available and useable. On my computer, there are four layouts available for Thai. I never enabled any of them, but if I had done that and used the layout, the odds are that it would a layout different from what you would try to make me use.

User input of characters can be challenging, but you cannot fix it by trying to set the keyboard layout. If you could set the layout in JavaScript (I think you cannot), you could seriously break the functionality when the user is accustomed to a completely different layout.

In some cases, an on-screen keyboard could solve part of the problem. For example, if users are expected to enter just a word or two in Thai and all the rest in English, you could embed a virtual keyboard with Thai character (and possibly hide it until a field for Thai input is focused on).

Technically, you could set the `lang` attribute on individual elements, like , and this would in principle be the right thing to do, but in practice, it hardly has any impact on anything now.

Comment: everything you say makes sense.  virtual keyboard might work for digits or date, but thai too complex (see comment above).  will test `lang`.

Comment: The `lang` attribute won’t do anything useful at present in this context.

A virtual keyboard can be designed to correspond to some common physical keyboard and logical layout used for Thai. I’m pretty sure people have done such things with code that could be re-used. See e.g. http://www.wandel.person.dk/thai.html and http://www.puttipan.com/thaikeyboard/